# How to import AdversarialModel, simple_gan, gan_targets in colab

Tags: python, keras, generative-adversarial-network

I am importing keras_adversarial and cloning its git too but it cannot import 'AdversarialModel'

i am working on gans, built generator and discriminator. now i want to combine them but colab is giving error while importing the modules of keras_adversarial

```
import keras_adversarial
from keras_adversarial import AdversarialModel, simple_gan, gan_targets
from keras_adversarial import AdversarialOptimizerSimultaneous, 
normal_latent_sampling

1 import keras_adversarial
----> 2 from keras_adversarial import AdversarialModel, simple_gan, 
gan_targets
3 from keras_adversarial import AdversarialOptimizerSimultaneous, 
normal_latent_sampling

ImportError: cannot import name 'AdversarialModel'
```

Answer (score 1):

The Colab environment only have a core set of packages installed. To add some third-party packages as `keras_adversarial`, you can execute installation script direcrly in Colab cells, with `!` symbol before each command to indicate that these are command line bash code, not Python.

In your case, you need to do:

```
!git clone https://github.com/bstriner/keras_adversarial.git
!cd keras_adversarial
!python setup.py install
```